# Django rest framework, JSON parsing

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

In django have file models.py:

```
class RawTransactionSale(models.Model):
    summ = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    sign = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    payments = models.JSONField(blank=False)
    merchant = models.JSONField(blank=False)


class PaymentTable(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    PaymentID = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, blank=False)
    paymentAmount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    raw_transaction_sale = models.ForeignKey('RawTransactionSale', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='raw_transaction_sale')


class MerchantTable(models.Model):
    merchantName = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    merchantID = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, blank=False)
    payment = models.ForeignKey('PaymentTable', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='merchant')
```

file serializers.py:

```
class PaymentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PaymentTable
        fields = '__all__'

class MerchantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MerchantTable
        fields = '__all__'

        
class RawTransactionSaleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RawTransactionSale
        fields = '__all__'
```

file views.py:

```
class RawTransactionSaleViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = RawTransactionSale.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RawTransactionSaleSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = RawTransactionSaleSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        validated_data = serializer.validated_data
        payments_data = validated_data.pop('payments')
        merchant_data = validated_data.pop('merchant')
        merchant_serializer = MerchantSerializer(data=merchant_data)
        merchant_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        merchant = merchant_serializer.save()
        raw_transaction_sale = RawTransactionSale.objects.create(merchant=merchant, **validated_data)
        for payment_data in payments_data:
            payment_data['raw_transaction_sale'] = raw_transaction_sale.id
            payment_serializer = PaymentSerializer(data=payment_data)
            payment_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            PaymentTable.objects.create(raw_transaction_sale=raw_transaction_sale, **payment_serializer.validated_data)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(raw_transaction_sale)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

In API recieve JSON:

```
{
    "summ": 1860.0,                                         
    "sign": "123456677531",
    "SaleMerchID": "ca9f9c0d-c2d0-321d-8b9a-123c3fc5b543",                  
    "merchant" : {
        "merchantName": "SuperShop",                            
        "merchantID" : "12345678-1234-abcd-dcab-123abc456def",                                              
        },
        
    "payments": [                                               
        {                                                       
            "date": "2023-04-27T15:50:15.000+0400",             
            "PaymentID": "4dba1234-f19e-1234-a432-ca5d15f9ec21",        
            "paymentAmount": 1860,                                                                      
        }
    ],
}
```

I'm try from JSON save payments in separated table PaymentTable, merchant in separated table MerchantTable, link with this transaction PaymentTable and MerchantTable, but have error "{"payment":["This field is required."]}". I think I'm trying to write data to table MerchantTable with a link to table PaymentTable, while table PaymentTable doesn't exist yet. But I don't know how to fix this.